# Magento2: facing this error en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/ placeholder/.jpg' [] []

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

How to resolve this error in magento2: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/themename/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/
placeholder/.jpg' [] []